# Pricing a European call option that has one underlying asset to compare with strike but 2 underlyings as payout

Tags: option-pricing, call, commodities, european

This is a real world problem and not a research one.

We are being proposed to buy an option that has to be exercised on a specific date T. So it is a European option.

This option has a strike price of K = 50. We are ITM if and only if the price of asset S1 is above K. So it is a call option.

However, if we choose to exercise the option we will receive S1 at a price of 50 - like for any call option, but also another asset S2 for free. This asset can then be sold on the market to make a profit. S1 and S2 are both future contracts for physical delivery of 2 different commodities.

So the payout of the call option would be assuming we are ITM:

P = (S1 - K) + S2

and so the price of the option should be the discounted expected payoff and so:

C = exp(-rT) E( max(S1 - K; 0) + S2 x Id)

Id is 1 when S1 >= K and 0 if not.

How can I price this option knowing that S1 alone is compared to the strike price and I will get S2 if I am ITM regardless of its price ?

I really have never seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

do a montecarlo simulation of both underlyings each having a gemetric brownian motion distribution with drift = risk free rate, and vol=vol of the underlying.
in such a way, you get values of each underlying in many scenarios.
then in each scenario, calculate your payoff
then average the payoffs
then discount that to the present
and that's your option price

hope that helps!

Comment: i was kind of hoping for a closed form equation as it would be easier to use and to calculate more exact derivatives

Comment: Can you clarify:   Is it (a) the option is auto exercised if S1>K or (b) you can choose whether to exercise (in which case you will exercise if S1+S2>K?   It seems like (a) but you use the word ‘choose’ in the question.

Comment: it is (a) definately not (b), but I mean you "choose" to call it since you have to call the counterparty and tell them you want to exercise.